# Find number of matrices $B$ with no common row and no common column with a given matrix $A$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, inclusion-exclusion

We are given a matrix $A$ with $n$ rows and $n$ columns and it's elements are $1,2,...,n^2$ (each element appears once). Find the number of matrices $B$ whose elements are $1,2,...,n^2$ that does not share a common row or a common column with $A$ (if it is not clear, we can't have the second row of $B$ to be equal to the fifth row of $A$, the non-equal rows (and columns) do not have to share index). 
 
I am pretty sure this uses inclusion-exclusion but I don't know how to approach it. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: You've tagged this as [tag:inclusion-exclusion]. Is there a specific reason for that? Also, if you're stuck, it's often a good idea to try a few small examples, like $n = 2$ or $3$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes. Earlier I solved the same question but without the non equal columns condition and it uses inclusion-exclusion, so I assume we should use it here too. I tried the small cases but I don't think it help to find the general formula which is likely quite ugly

Comment: A first consequence is that $A-B$ is not invertible, but I suspect if this really helps.

Comment: It shouldn't use linear algebra, this is taken from an indroductary combinatorics exam